# ClassLoader.loadLibrary NullPointerException in Adopt OpenJDK 11.0.8

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, classloader

I am getting Class loader NullPointerException at many places while testing the product with Adopt Open JDK 11.0.7 or 11.0.8.
And everything goes fine with Adopt OpenJDK 11.0.6.
Below is the exception:

**Exception 1**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystem.newWatchService(LinuxFileSystem.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2646)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService$1.run(LinuxWatchService.java:464)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService$1.run(LinuxWatchService.java:462)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService.<clinit>(LinuxWatchService.java:462)
        ... 3 more
```

**Exception 2**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2646)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipUtils.loadLibrary(ZipUtils.java:285)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.Deflater.<clinit>(Deflater.java:193)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: Does this occur in Java 12 or later?